# Constructing an SQL query to insert into a database

Tags: forms, racket

I have submitted the form to the same page and I am able to display the submitted values, but when I try to insert the submitted/posted values, I am struggling with the syntax. How do I access the value as a variable?   What is the right way of writing this line and where do I bring in the insert query?

```
(query-exec sql-exp
            "insert into students(name) values ( '`post-body a-post')")
```

I am able to display the values with the code below:

```
; render-post: post -> xexpr
; Consumes a post, produces an xexpr fragment of the post.
(define (render-post a-post)
  `(div ((class "post"))
        "Title : "
        ,(post-title a-post)
        (p ,"Post : "
         ,(post-body a-post))))


; render-posts: blog -> xexpr
; Consumes a blog, produces an xexpr fragment
; of all its posts.
(define (render-posts a-blog)
  `(div ((class "posts"))        
        ,@(map render-post a-blog)))
```

Comment: Have you already looked at the following?  http://docs.racket-lang.org/continue/index.html

Comment: yeh i did, but couldnt make it work..i am missing something..please share 1 simple example if possible..with 

1.HTML form submits the form via POST method to a servlet
2.A servlet that prints a posted values

Comment: Do you have a firewall and/or antivirus that blocks the port on your Windows machine?

Comment: Please be specific by "couldn't make it work".  To solve technical problems like this, we need to know what you're seeing, and by simply reporting a failure, there's very little content to reproduce what you're seeing, or to know what you mean.  Be specific.  Were you ever able to run the very first example in the Continue tutorial?  What error message did you receive, if any?

Comment: Have edited the post and tried to explain the problem..sorry for not being specific before, i was hoping some one would have a very simple example catering a similar requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The second example in the [documentation for query-exec](http://docs.racket-lang.org/db/query-api.html#%28def._%28%28lib._db/base..rkt%29._query-exec%29%29) shows how to execute database queries that take in parameters.

For example, assuming we have a `food` table with `name` and `calories` columns, we can write a function that can insert into that table.

```
;; insert-food!: database-connection string number -> void
;; Inserts an element into the food table.
(define (insert-food! conn name cals)
  (query-exec conn
              "insert into food (name, calories) values ($1, $2)" 
              name
              cals))
```

We are using a [parameterized query](http://docs.racket-lang.org/db/query-api.html#%28tech._parameterized._query%29), assuming the database is PostgreSQL or some database that supports using the placeholders `$1`, `$2`... etc, and passing values for those placeholders as additional arguments to `query-exec`.

If you are taking input from the external world and constructing an SQL query with it, you **should** know how to use parameterized queries, or else you're risking the safety of your database.  Do **not** try to format a single string that interpolates the values of your variables all into one query string: you'll likely get it very wrong and open your program to an [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) exploit.  Instead, pass those values as distinct arguments to `query-exec`.

Also, note that the function above doesn't need to be used in the context of web servers: it can be used in the context of [unit testing](http://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/index.html), for example.  You probably *want* to test this function without requiring it to be used in a web servlet.  Something like this:

```
#lang racket

(require db)

;; We want to export the following functions to outside clients.
(provide [struct-out foo]
         insert-food!
         get-foods!)


;; A food is a:
(struct food (name ;; string
              cals) ;; number
  #:transparent)


;; insert-food!: database-connection food -> void
;; Inserts an element into the food table.
(define (insert-food! conn a-food)
  (query-exec conn
              "insert into food (name, calories) values ($1, $2)" 
              (food-name a-food)
              (food-cals a-food)))


;; get-foods!: database-connection -> (listof food)
;; Get a list of the foods in the database.
(define (get-foods! conn)
  (for/list ([(name cal)
              (in-query conn "select name, calories from food")])
    (food name cal)))


(module+ test
  (require rackunit)
  ;; Internal test.  We'll use an in-memory SQLite database.
  (define conn (sqlite3-connect #:database 'memory))
  (query-exec conn "create table food (name string, calories double)")

  ;; Initially, it should be empty.
  (check-equal? (get-foods! conn) '())

  ;; Now let's add a food:

  ;; http://www.eiyoukeisan.com/JapaneseFoodCalorie/zryouri/misoramen.html
  (insert-food! conn (food "miso ramen" 56000.0))

  ;; Can we get it back?
  (check-equal? (get-foods! conn) (list (food "miso ramen" 56000.0))))
```

Now you can test the functionality of these database functions by running this file in DrRacket.  Once we know that they work reliably, then we can use them in different contexts such as web servlets.

Trying to do this all in the same place as a HTTP request handler is likely the wrong approach.  You want your data model, the database operations, to be in a separate module from your HTTP request handlers, or else risk making the data model very hard to test.  That's the main reason the [Continue web-server tutorial](http://docs.racket-lang.org/continue/index.html) goes out of its way to talk about extracting out a "model" as a separate module.