# Submitting a HTML form to servlet in Racket

Tags: forms, servlets, racket

Can someone share an Example with a

1. HTML form submits the form via POST method to a servlet
2. A servlet that prints a posted values

Comment: possible duplicate of [Racket : submitting a form to a servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866490/racket-submitting-a-form-to-a-servlet)

Answer (score 2):

See the following example from the web-server collection.

https://github.com/racket/web-server/blob/master/web-server-lib/web-server/default-web-root/htdocs/servlets/examples/add-page.rkt

Comment: @BIvanov  The file was moved. I have inserted a new link.